# Understanding numerator/denominator layout in matrix-calculus

Tags: derivatives, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus, machine-learning, neural-networks

> This is a distilled version of [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/553883/248568) question.

Consider the following:
$$
\begin{align}
z & = f(\mathbf{y}) \\
\mathbf{y} & = g(\mathbf{x}) \\
\text{where, } & z \in \mathbb{R} \text{, and} \\
& \mathbf{y}, \mathbf{x} \text{ are two $(1, m)$ dimensional vectors, i.e. row-vectors}
\end{align}
$$

**Using numerator-layout**, what is the dimension of the derivative $\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{y}}$?

- Should it be a column-vector of dimension $(m, 1)$, because $\mathbf{y}$ is a row-vector of dimension $(1, m)$ ([Source](https://github.com/LynnHo/Matrix-Calculus))

  - But, using this notation **causes issues** while computing the derivative $\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{x}} = \frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{y}} \frac{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{y}}{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{x}}$; since, $\frac{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{y}}{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{x}}$ would be an $(m, m)$ matrix, while $\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{y}}$ is an $(m, 1)$ vector.
  - However, this notation **does serve well** when computing the derivatives of the form $\frac{\mathrm{d} h(\mathbf{X})}{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{X}}$, where $\mathbf{X}$ is a matrix of dimension $(m, n)$; and $h(\mathbf{X})$ is a scalar-valued function.
- Or should it be a row-vector, because according to the numerator-layout the derivative has the dimensions --> $\text{numerator-dimension} \times (\text{denominator-dimension})^\intercal = (1,1)\times(m, 1)$ ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Other_matrix_derivatives))

  - Also, (for this point) is my understanding even correct?

**PS:** also, is there any definitive guide from which I can learn matrix-calculus from the first principals. Although, the following sources are good, they still leave a lot of gaps:

- [Matrix-Calculus](https://github.com/LynnHo/Matrix-Calculus)
- [The Matrix-cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf)
- [Old and New Matrix Algebra Useful for Statistics](https://tminka.github.io/papers/matrix/minka-matrix.pdf), by T. P. Minka
- [The Matrix Calculus You Need For Deep Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.01528)
- [Matrix Differentiation](https://atmos.washington.edu/%7Edennis/MatrixCalculus.pdf)
- [Matrix Calculus](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Edattorro/matrixcalc.pdf)
- [The Guide for Matrix Calculus](https://tapyu.github.io/notes/posts/matrix_diff_ref/index.html), by R.P. Pacelli.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}(#1)}
\def\shape#1{\operatorname{shape}(#1)}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\p{\partial}\def\o{\tt1}\def\z{\zeta}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}} 
$Let's use a convention where uppercase Latin denotes a matrix, lowercase Latin a vector, and Greek letters are scalars. Always write the column vector as $y$ and the corresponding row vector as $y^T$. Finally, let's use a colon to denote the matrix inner product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij}\;=\;\trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
When applied to column $\big(n=\o\big)$
or row $\big(m=\o\big)$ vectors this corresponds to the usual dot product.

Now write the functions using column vectors, and calculate their Jacobians, gradients and differentials as
$$\eqalign{
y &= y(x) \qiq J=\grad{y}{x} &\qiq dy = J\,dx \\
\z &= \z(y) \qiq g = \grad{\z}{y} &\qiq d\zeta = g:dy \\
}$$
Now calculate the gradient of $\z$ with respect to $x$ by back substitution
$$\eqalign{
d\z &= g:dy = g:J\,dx = J^Tg:dx \\
\grad{\z}{x} &= J^Tg = \LR{\grad{y}{x}}^T\LR{\grad{\z}{y}} \\
}$$
Next, consider the case of a matrix argument $Y$
$$\eqalign{
\z &= \z(Y) \qiq G = \grad{\z}{Y} &\qiq d\z = G:dY \\
}$$
In general, the shape of the gradient of a scalar-valued function should match the shape of the independent variable, e.g. $\shape{g}=\shape{y}\;$ and $\;\shape{G}=\shape{Y}$.

The shape of the Jacobian of a vector-value function is such that it can be dotted with the independent vector, i.e. such that $\,J\,dx\;$ is dimensionally compatible.

---

To make the formulas work with row vectors, simply transpose **everything.**
$$\eqalign{
y^T &= y^T(x^T) &\qiq dy^T = dx^TJ^T \\
\z &= \z(y^T) &\qiq g^T = \grad{\z}{y^T} \\
\\
d\z &= dy^T:g^T \\&= dx^TJ^T:g^T \\&= dx^T:g^TJ \\
\grad{\z}{x^T} &= g^TJ \\
\\
}$$